# How to prevent system from taking the sentinel value as an input?

Tags: c, loops, sentinel

So, i created a simple program for user to enter temperature and calculate the highest, lowest, average. After user entered the sentinel value to stop the loop, somehow the sentinel value will also be taken as input and messed up the data, here is my code, kindly help me to take a look if u have time, thanks a lot

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int temperature, highest = 0, lowest = 0, counter = 1, counter2 = 0, total = 0;
    float average;
    
    printf("Enter temperature (-999 to stop) > ");
    scanf("%d", &temperature);
    
    if (temperature == -999) {
    printf("No temperature is captured.");
    return 0;
    }
    
    else if (temperature > 40)
    counter2++;
    
    do {
        printf("Enter temperature (-999 to stop) > ");
        scanf("%d", &temperature);
        
        if (temperature >= highest)
        highest = temperature;
        
        if (temperature <= lowest)
        lowest = temperature;
        
        if (temperature > 40)
        counter2++;
        
        total += temperature;
        counter++;
    } while (temperature != -999);
    
    average = total / counter;
    
    printf("Total days with temperature more than 40'C > %d\n", counter2);
    printf("The lowest temperature  > %d\n", lowest);
    printf("The highest temperature > %d\n", highest);
    printf("Average of temperature  > %.2f\n", average);
}
```

Comment: step through the code. If you don't want it to record -999 then may I suggest an "if" statement (every time, not just the first one).

Comment: What @KennyOstrom said. It's not strange that it continues if you don't write any code to prevent it.

Comment: Ooh is it ok if i add if ( temperature == 999 ) break; after the first scanf in the loop so that the calculation after it will not include the -999? @ke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You include the sentinel (-999) because you add the value **before** you reach the code that test for the sentinel value. You need to test **immediately after** you take the input.

But even if that is fixed, there are more problems.

You start by setting `lowest` to zero, so if I input 20 followed by -999, then `lowest` will still be zero.

You **do not** save the first input (except incrementing `count2`) so your final result will be wrong. Again, if I input 20 followed by -999, then `total` will be zero (assuming we already fixed the sentinel problem). And if I input 20 40 -999, `total` will only be 40 and average will be 20 because `count` is incremented twice.

Further, you should always check the `scanf` return value.

So you need to re-organise your code. For instance like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int temperature, highest = 0, lowest = 0, counter = 0, counter2 = 0, total = 0;
    float average;
    
    printf("Enter temperature (-999 to stop) > ");
    if (scanf("%d", &temperature) != 1) exit(1);
    
    if (temperature == -999) {
    printf("No temperature is captured.");
    return 0;
    }
    
    lowest = temperature;
    highest = temperature;

    do {
        
        if (temperature >= highest)
        highest = temperature;
        
        if (temperature <= lowest)
        lowest = temperature;
        
        if (temperature > 40)
        counter2++;
        
        total += temperature;
        counter++;

        printf("Enter temperature (-999 to stop) > ");
        if (scanf("%d", &temperature) != 1) exit(1);
    } while (temperature != -999);
    
    average = total / counter;
    
    printf("Total days with temperature more than 40'C > %d\n", counter2);
    printf("The lowest temperature  > %d\n", lowest);
    printf("The highest temperature > %d\n", highest);
    printf("Average of temperature  > %.2f\n", average);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is overly complicated. Why do you have the first temperature input out of the loop? There is nothing special about the first input.

You want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int temperature, highest = 0, lowest = 0, counter = 1, counter2 = 0, total = 0;
  float average;

  do {
    printf("Enter temperature (-999 to stop) > ");
    scanf("%d", &temperature);

    if (temperature == -999)
      break;

    if (temperature >= highest)
      highest = temperature;

    if (temperature <= lowest)
      lowest = temperature;

    if (temperature > 40)
      counter2++;

    total += temperature;
    counter++;
  } while (temperature != -999);

  average = total / counter;

  printf("Total days with temperature more than 40'C > %d\n", counter2);
  printf("The lowest temperature  > %d\n", lowest);
  printf("The highest temperature > %d\n", highest);
  printf("Average of temperature  > %.2f\n", average);
}
```

There are still some bugs, and if you enter no temperature at all, the program doesn't work correctly. But I let you that by yourself. It shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: am i supposed to change the break; to return 0; ?

Comment: No, this is not a problem. Why return 0 from insted of the break? Basically if you enter -999 you want to stop the loop. But look what happens if you enter -999 as the first number. And also check if the _lowest_ temperature is displayed correctly.

Comment: but sorry i cant find any error since all the data is 0, like highest, lowest and average, can you be more specific?

Comment: For example enter 3 temperatures 7,8, and 9. Now look what the program displays for the lowest temperature.